# How to resolve this error :Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin-coroutines

I got this error and added some logs to see what was going on and I am a bit confused.

I have 3 fragments, Category, Symbol, Meaning. The each have a recyclerview. The initial fragment for the app is CategoryFragment. It shows the list of categories and when a category is selected it navigates to SymbolFragment. This shows a list of symbols and when you click on one of them it navigates you to MeaningFragment. All of the data in the various lists are in a Room database.

This is what the Category section looks like:

```
Log.d("Dreams", "Category before Coroutine Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().name.toString())
        viewModel.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Log.d("Dreams", "Category in Coroutine Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().name.toString())
            viewModel.getAllCategories().collect() {
                categoryAdapter.submitList(it)
            }

        }
```

This Category one does not cause the Exception. The code works fine
When this is run the Log shows:

```
D/Dreams: Category before Coroutine Thread: main
D/Dreams: Category in Coroutine Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
```

The SymbolFragment code looks like this:

```
Log.d("Dreams", "Symbol before Coroutine Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().name.toString())
        //lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
        viewModel.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Log.d("Dreams", "Symbol in Coroutine Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().name.toString())
            viewModel.symbolIdentitiesByCategoryIdentity(categoryIdentity).collect() {
                symbolAdapter.submitList(it)
            }
        }
```

This DOES generate the Exception and the log shows:

```
D/Dreams: Symbol before Coroutine Thread: main
D/Dreams: Symbol in Coroutine Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
```

If I un-comment the lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch line and
comment the viewModel.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO),
the Symbol Fragment runs fine. The log looks like this:

```
D/Dreams: Symbol before Coroutine Thread: main
D/Dreams: Symbol in Coroutine Thread: main
```

This makes sense since both are on main.

The Meaning Fragment has the same behavior as the Symbol Fragment.

But this leaves me with a couple of questions:

1. Why does Category not get an error since the threads are
   different after
   viewModel.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) ?
2. In Symbol, lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch does keep me on
   main allowing me to update the symbolAdapter's List. However,
   I don't think I want to be on main because
   viewModel.symbolIdentitiesByCategory() accesses a Room DB
   which does I/O. I think you don't want to do I/O on main.

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: "viewModel.symbolIdentitiesByCategory() accesses a Room DB
which does I/O" -- Room supplies its own background thread for the `Flow` that it returns. I am guessing that this function returns a `Flow`, since you are calling `collect()` on it. I would only call `submitList()` from the main application thread. Even if you still feel that you need `Dispatchers.IO`, you would wrap the `submitList()` call in `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` to move that piece of the coroutine to the main application thread.

Comment: I like your reccomendation of using withCntext(Dispatcher.Main) around symbolAdapter.submitList(it). It works like a champ and I mostly understand it. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 4):

It will be safest to call `submitList()` from the main application thread.

You should not need `Dispatchers.IO` here, if `symbolIdentitiesByCategory()` returns a `Flow`. Room uses its own dispatcher for that flow; you would specify the dispatcher on which you wanted to collect the data.

But, for cases, where you do indeed need `Dispatchers.IO` for some work, you can switch back to the main application thread using `withContext()`:

```kotlin
viewModel.viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  viewModel.symbolIdentitiesByCategoryIdentity(categoryIdentity).collect() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
      symbolAdapter.submitList(it)
    }
  }
}
```